# Sum of binomial coefficients in Gould tables

Tags: binomial-coefficients, roots-of-unity, trigonometric-series

Consider the combinatorial identity by Gould, [Table III](https://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.6.PDF), page 25, equation (6.13):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{[\frac{n}{r}]}{n \choose rk}=\frac{2^n}{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\left(\cos{\frac{\pi j}{r}}\right)^n\cos{\frac{n \pi j}{r}} \tag{6.13}$$

and replace $n$ with $rn$ to get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{rn \choose rk}=\frac{2^{rn}}{r}\sum_{j=1}^{r}\left(\cos{\frac{\pi j}{r}}\right)^{rn}\cos{n \pi j} \tag{6.13M}$$

For cases $r=3$ and $r=4$ it is shown that this formula simplifies to (6.15) and (6.17) respectively, for example:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{3n \choose 3k}=\frac{1}{3}\left(2^{3n}+2(-1)^n\right)\tag{6.15}$$

Do you think it is possible to generalize (6.15) and (6.17) for any natural $r$ (or $r$ of some form), obtaining an expression with all integers, and if yes how?

Note that this question is related to [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887978/binomial-coefficients-involving-prime-powers-minus-1).

Comment: the cosine makes it difficult to evaluate when your $r$ is not $2,3,4$ or $6$ as evaluation of the cosine function is simple at "nice" angles.

Comment: Some observations from data: It seems that for fixed $r$ it is always possible to write $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{rn}{rk}$ as a recurrence of order $\lceil r/2\rceil$ with integer coefficients. For example for $r=3$ we have $a_n=7a_{n-1}+8a_{n-2}$, for $r=4$ it is $a_n=12a_{n-1}+64a_{n-2}$, etc. Coefficients at $a_{n-1}$ in such recurrence seem to be $2^{r-2}+r-1$. Being able to spot patterns in other coefficients, one might write recurrence formula for $a_{n}$ in integers only....

Comment: Consult [OEIS A070782](https://oeis.org/A070782) where already square roots appear in the closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^n {5n\choose 5k}$. We may cancel these similar to Fibonacci numbers. This yields a sum and not a closed form, however.

Comment: Identity (6.11) in Gould is easier to work with than (6.13). For example, one can use it in a finite field to show divisibility by p in [the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887978/binomial-coefficients-involving-prime-powers-minus-1). It can be also used to write the sequence in @Sil's comment as a linear recurrence with integer coefficients.