# Understanding solution of binomial problem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am reading this ["Amazing properties of binomial coefficients"](https://www.turgor.ru/lktg/2012/1/1-1en.pdf) and particularly problem 1.6 on page 1 and its "Solution 1" on page 7.

What I don't understand is when they recombine sums in the last passage of the proof on page 8 "Now transform the sum from the problem statement: ...".

Anyone can help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show by induction on $n$: If $1\leq j,k\leq p-1$ and $n\equiv k \pmod{p-1}$ then
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{j}+\binom{n}{(p-1)+j}+\binom{n}{2(p-1)+j}+\binom{n}{3(p-1)+j}+\cdots\equiv \binom{k}{j} \pmod{p}
\end{align*}

The recombination of the sums, OP is asking for, is an essential part of the induction step. To better see what's going on we look at the entire induction step.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{l\geq 0}&\binom{n}{l(p-1)+j}\\
> &=\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{m+(p-1)}{l(p-1)+j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{l\geq 0}\sum_{i=0}^{\min\{l(p-1)+j,p-1\}}\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j-i}\binom{p-1}{i}\tag{2}\\
> &\equiv \sum_{l\geq 0}\sum_{i=0}^{\min\{l(p-1)+j,p-1\}}(-1)^i\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j-i}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^i\binom{m}{j-i}+\sum_{l>0}\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j-i}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^i\binom{m}{j-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{m}{p-1+j-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\binom{m}{2(p-1)+j-i}+\cdots\tag{5}\\
> &=\left[\color{blue}{\binom{m}{j}}-\binom{m}{j-1}+\cdots-(-1)^j\binom{m}{1}+(-1)^j\binom{m}{0}\right]\\
> &\qquad +\left[\color{blue}{\binom{m}{(p-1)+j}}-\binom{m}{(p-1)+j-1}+\cdots+\binom{m}{j}\right]\\
> &\qquad +\left[\color{blue}{\binom{m}{2(p-1)+j}}-\binom{m}{2(p-1)+j-1}+\cdots+\binom{m}{(p-1)+j}\right]\tag{6}\\
> &\qquad \ \,\vdots\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j}}\\
> &\qquad+\left[(-1)^j\binom{m}{0}-(-1)^j\binom{m}{1}+\cdots-\binom{m}{j-1}\right]\\
> &\qquad+\left[\binom{m}{j}-\binom{m}{j+1}+\cdots-\binom{m}{(p-1)+j-1}\right]\\
> &\qquad+\left[\binom{m}{(p-1)+j}-\binom{m}{(p-1)+j+1}+\cdots+\binom{m}{2(p-1)+j-1}\right]\tag{7}\\
> &\qquad \ \,\vdots\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j}}+(-1)^j\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}(-1)^i\tag{8}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j}}+(-1)^j(1-1)^m\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{l\geq 0}\binom{m}{l(p-1)+j}}\\
> &\equiv \binom{k}{j}\pmod{p}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}
>   and the induction step is completed.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we set $n=m+p-1$.
- In (2) we apply the *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*.
  We explicitly set  lower and upper index of the inner sum which will be useful in the next steps.
- In (3) we use $\binom{p-1}{i}\equiv (-1)^i\pmod{p}$ corresponding to problem 1.1.a in the paper.
- In (4) we split the summand with $l=0$ since the inner sum has upper limit $j$ while in all other cases ($l>0$) the inner sum has upper limit $p-1$.
- In (5) we write the summands with $l=0,1$ and $l=2$ explicitly.
- In (6) we expand each of the sums with $l=0,1$ and $l=2$.
- In (7) we collect the first summand (marked in blue) of each of the sums and write the other summands in reverse order.
- In (8) we observe that all the terms from the expanded sums are consecutive terms starting with $(-1)^j\binom{m}{0}$ and they can be written as one sum.
- In (9) we apply the induction hypothesis.

> *Note:* In the paper there is a typo in the derivation of the formula on page 8. In the expression
>   \begin{align*}
> +\left(\binom{m}{2(p-1)+j}-\binom{m}{2(p-1)+j-1}+\cdots +\binom{m}{\color{blue}{2}(p-1)+j}\right)+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   the blue marked factor $\color{blue}{2}$ is not correct and should be deleted. The last summand is $\binom{m}{(p-1)+j}$.

Comment: Thank you! This is working with $j =0$ too, right?

Comment: @mbjoe: You're welcome. I think the range of validity starting with $j=1$ is correct. Note that the simpler formula with $j=0$ in example 1.6 starts with $\binom{n}{p-1}$ and not with $\binom{n}{0}$. Take e.g. the example $p=7,n=12,k=6$ and $j\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Rethinking about it I should replace $j = p-1$ then. By the way I was trying to apply that problem's result to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887978/binomial-coefficients-involving-prime-powers-minus-1).