# Evaluating the sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{15} (-1)^k \cos^{560} (k\pi/16).$

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, summation

To eliminate the pesky $(-1)^k$ term, I have rewritten this as

$ S = -\sum\limits_{k=0}^{15} \cos^{560} (k\pi/16) + 2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{7} \cos^{560} (k\pi/8).$

However, neither of these sums are easy to evaluate. I think that the next step would be finding the minimal polynomial of $1, \cos(\pi/8), \dots, \cos(7\pi/8).$ However, this is just a factor of $T_{16}(x)-1$ where $T_n(x)$ is the $n$th degree Chebyshev Polynomial. This route is clearly messy before we even start factoring. The other sum would be even worse to handle.

I'm wondering if there are any other approaches for computing $S.$

Comment: I can't accurately tell but I sense some use of Binomial theorem and complex numbers (Using De'Moivre's formula) to solve. But still it's just a guess :-))

Comment: Seems De Moivre is applicable, but the computation is still "gruesome"…

Comment: @xbh I have already thought about this. Unfortunately, $\Re(z)^{560} \ne \Re(z^{560}),$ so I cannot just perform calculations with complex numbers and take the real part to finish off.

Comment: On second thought, I now see what you meant, and I agree that it will be ugly.

Comment: By the way, would it help if I knew that $2^{560}S$ is an integer (due to how the problem was asked)?

Comment: Looks like $S\approx \cos\left(\frac\pi{180}\right)$

Comment: This looks like it's related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2879650/5676

Answer (score 1):

Let us compute the number using [sage](http://www.sagemath.org), the needed two lines

```
K.<z> = CyclotomicField( 32 )
print sum( [ (-1)^k * ( (z^k + z^-k) / 2 )^560 for k in [0..15] ] )
```

will be slightly expanded, so that the human eye can easily digest them, above `z` is $\zeta_{32}\sim\exp(2\pi i/32)$ a primitive root of unity of order $32$, sage works algebraically (exactly), the (also by sage) preferred  embedding in $\Bbb C$ can be easily changed:

```
sage: K.<z> = CyclotomicField( 32 )
sage: z.complex_embedding()
0.980785280403230 + 0.195090322016128*I
sage: cos(2*pi/32).n()
0.980785280403230
sage: A = sum( [ (-1)^k * ( (z^k + z^-k) / 2 )^560 for k in [0..15] ] )
sage: A = QQ(A)
sage: A.denom().factor()
2^487
sage: A.numer()
399568537235075894687625168713672502385259077051830433046200439695346621697198388130048600447044762506823601999970295738124406324872353832659479279
```

This writes the given sum as a rational number with denominator $2^{487}$ and a numerator as above. (Do we expect something special about this number, expected to be rational with a two-power as denominator?!)

Comment: I knew that $2^{560}S$ had to be an integer before I started solving the problem, which explains your result.